# Pandas - Looking to convert int based window to time based window

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is being pulled at different rates. This is causing my model to break cause these my predefined rolling windows span different time periods for each dataset. With that, I have attempted to convert my rolling windows to time but I'm running into some issues.

Original Rolling Functions:

```
df['rb_price_rolling_150'] = df['rb_price'].rolling(150).mean()
df['rb_price_rolling_25000'] = df['rb_price'].rolling(25000).mean()
df['rb_price_rolling_50000'] = df['rb_price'].rolling(50000).mean()
```

My thought was to look at the duration between each of these rolling windows. Here they are:

```
print(tracker_df_local.time.min())
print(tracker_df_local.iloc[:150].time.max())
print(tracker_df_local.iloc[:25000].time.max())
print(tracker_df_local.iloc[:50000].time.max())

2020-05-03 11:55:28.387734
2020-05-03 11:55:52.911642
2020-05-03 13:01:40.231135
2020-05-03 14:08:54.740307
```

Now, I found that these time based windows are approximately `20s`, `1h` and `2hr`.

I've updated my code as follows:

```
tracker_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(tracker_df['time'])
tracker_df = tracker_df.set_index('time')

df['rb_price_rolling_150'] = df['rb_price'].rolling('20s', min_periods = 1).mean()
df['rb_price_rolling_25000'] = df['rb_price'].rolling('1h', min_periods = 1).mean()
df['rb_price_rolling_50000'] = df['rb_price'].rolling('2h', min_periods = 1).mean()
```

When I did this, my plots and results were completely off. Here is an example:

```
tracker_df_ctrl['rb_price'].rolling(150)
Rolling [window=150,center=False,axis=0]


tracker_df_test['rb_price'].rolling('25s')
Rolling [window=25000000000,min_periods=1,center=False,win_type=freq,axis=0]
```

For some reason, the actual window size is completely different. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, let me know if any more detail is required.

Comment: You solution looks right to me. What is 'way off' with your result?

Comment: i've added an edit that provides an example.

Comment: Is your index date time?

Comment: yes, I converted my time column to pandas datetime then set that as my index.